# parsing json postgresql query

Tags: json, postgresql

Here is my postgresql query..

```
select mc."appointmentId" as app_id,

mc."dateLeadSubmitted"::timestamp(0) without time zone::text as created,

extract(week from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") as created_week,

extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") as Created_Day,

extract(month from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") as Created_Month,

extract(year from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") as Created_Year, 

CASE when extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") = 6 then 'Saturday'
 when extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") = 5 then 'Friday'
 when extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") = 4 then 'Thursday'
 when extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") = 3 then 'Wednesday'
 when extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") = 2 then 'Tuesday'
 when extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") = 1 then 'Monday'
 when extract(dow from mc."dateLeadSubmitted") = 0 then 'Sunday' end as Day,
 
mc."fullName" as customer_name,

mc."leadSourceType" as Lead_Source,

mc."setterId" as setter_id,

su."fullName" as Setter,

su."createdAt" as Start_date,

mc."salesRepId" as closer_id,

r."fullName" as Closer,

mc.region as region, 

mc.team as regional,  

mc."vOutcome" as valor_outcome,

mc."dOutcome" as dauntless_outcome,

mc."fluentApprovedDate"::timestamp(0) without time zone::text as FA_date,

mc."contractSignedDate"::timestamp(0) without time zone::text as Booked_date,

mc."siteSurveyCompleteDate"::timestamp(0) without time zone::text as Sitesurvey_date,

mc."dateAllPermitsApproved"::timestamp(0) without time zone::text as permits_approved,


o.name as Location






from "MasterCustomer" mc 

left join "SalesRep" r on r.id = mc."salesRepId"

left join "Setter" su on su.id = mc."setterId"

left join "Office" o on o.id = r."officeId"

Where mc."dateLeadSubmitted" is not null and mc."leadSourceType" = 'Setter' and mc."dateLeadSubmitted" >= '2021-01-01'

order by mc."dateLeadSubmitted" desc

limit 50
```

everything works except mc."vOutcome" as valor_outcome gives me the following JSON in the cell

```
[{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Failed Credit","id":11,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: No Show","id":3,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: No Tax Incentive","id":7,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Shaded","id":8,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Other (See Notes)","id":2,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":true},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Renter","id":9,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Not Interested","id":5,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Pending","id":10,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Closed","id":1,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Missed","id":6,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Manually Set by Fluent","id":12,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"deleted","text":"Not Pitched: Other (See Notes)","id":4,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false}]
```

Based on the "Selected": True, I want to pull the "Text":(I want just this lone answer in my cell). so in this example, it would be Not Pitched: Other

thanks in advance

Comment: You asked almost the same question some time ago

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing Json postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630415/parsing-json-postgresql)